# Telerik MVC Extensions to KendoUI for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I need to migrate my grid code from MVC Extensions to KendoUI. Are there any tools or migration lists that can help me to quickly migrate something like this?

```
    <div id="divChargesGrid" style="overflow: hidden; height: auto">
         @(Html.Telerik().Grid<SAM.Framework.Utilities.CloneClasses.vxChargeBO>(Model.VXChargeBOs)
        .Name("ChargesGrid")
        .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.ChargeID))

        .Columns(columns =>
        {

          columns.Bound(c => c.ChargeID).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.ChargeNo)
           .ClientTemplate("<a href='/Billing/Charge/Edit/<#= ChargeID #>?yz=<#= AgencyObfuscated #>'> <#= ChargeNo #> </a>")
              .Width(85).Title("Charge No.");
          columns.Bound(c => c.ChargeStatusType).Title("Status").Width(75);
          columns.Bound(c => c.ServiceDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(100).Title("Date of Service");
          columns.Bound(c => c.ChargeCodeDescription).Title("Description").Width(100);
          columns.Bound(c => c.PatientNo).Title("Patient No.").Width(85);

          columns.Bound(c => c.Mileage).Title("Mileage").Width(75);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Active).Width(75);
          columns.Bound(c => c.UpdatedDate).Width(100).Format("{0:d}").Title("Updated Date");
          columns.Bound(c => c.UpdatedBy).Width(100).Title("Updated By");
          columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedDate).Width(100).Format("{0:d}").Title("Created Date");
          columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedBy).Width(100).Title("Created By");

          columns.Bound(c => c.Agency).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.PatientID).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.AdmissionID).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.AdmissionNo).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.BatchNo).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.EpisodeID).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.ChargeStatusTypeID).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(c => c.UnitCode).Hidden(true);


        })
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onChargesGridDataBinding").OnDataBound("onChargesGridDataBound"))
  .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GridChargeIndexSelect", "Charge", new { @Agency = Model.AgencyProfile.Agency
      , @startDate = Model.FromDate, @endDate = Model.ToDate, @employeeSearchText = Model.EmployeeSearchText, @patientSearchText = Model.PatientSearchText
      , @whichSearch = Model.WhichSearch, @ShowPosted = Model.ShowPosted, @ShowNotPosted = Model.ShowNotPosted, @ShowResults = Model.ShowResults }))
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
        .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true).PageSize(15))
        .Filterable()
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(400))
        .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:99.8%;" })
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no tool but the documentation has some instructions:

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/migration/migrating-from-telerik-extensions-for-aspnet-mvc

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/migration/widgets/grid